# Check javascript/css files modification time on every request

Tags: php, javascript, html

We have two files in header of every web page - a ccs and a javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js?1234"></script>
<link href="styles.css?2345" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Every time we modify a css/javascript file we increase the **?1234** parameter in the end of filename. Recently a member of the team proposed to replace this manual updating (that we have sometimes forgot to do) with PHP code that checks the file modification time itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js?<?php echo filemtime('/js/scripts.js');?>"/>
<link href="styles.css?<?php echo filemtime('styles.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The question is that how much slower (if at all) it makes the requests? Should we do it? We run our system in Linux server on Amazon EC2.

Comment: It's likely not to be noticeably slower. But the best way is to simply try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filetime is slow but using it 2 times in a webpage maybe ok. But I would cache the result and only update it sometime (with a conjob for example).

> Well if you are checking 1000 files, filemtime will actually DOUBLE
>   the amount of time used if just reading the file with
>   file_get_contents!

-> http://ckon.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/filemtime-the-performance-killer/

Answer (score 0):

Execute this on your server:

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; ++$i) {
    filemtime('styles.css');
    filemtime('/js/scripts.js'); //Seriously, is this file on the root of you server? I don't think so :)
}
echo 'Seconds slower: ' . ((microtime(true) - $start) / 5000) . '.';
```

And it will give you the seconds :)

But, how often do you change an CSS & JS file? If it's every minute, than it's really helpful, but if it's every month, it's useless I think.

Comment: I shortened the path for clarity ;-)

Comment: If you call filemtime() in a row you might get response from harddisk very fast (as its head doesn't have to move). Also if there exists a php per-request-cache then this benchmark will show faster times than in real life.